# How to extract 'hello' from the following nested dictionary using indexing?

Tags: python, indexing

> How can I extract hello from the code using indexing?

```
I_say = {'stairs_1':[1, 'two', {'stairs_2':['Close to the door', {'in the door':['one', 2, ['hello']]}]}]}
```

Comment: `I_say["stairs_1"][2]["stairs_2"][1]["in the door"][-1][0]`?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: The shortest code using indexing would be something like `print(str(I_say)[88:93])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help you immensely if you'd reformat your code and make it more readable.

```json
{
  "stairs_1":[
    1,
    "two",
    {
      "stairs_2":[
        "Close to the door",
        {
          "in the door":[
            "one",
            2,
            [
              "hello"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After looking at this code, you can see that the first level is a dictionary with a key `stairs_1`, its value is a list of three values.

The third value is a dictionary that contains just one element. Again, `stairs_2` is the key and the value is a list, this time of two elements.

The second element is a dictionary that contains one element, its key is `in the door` and the value is a list.

The list contains three elements, while the third one is a list with a single element - your `"hello"` string.

So the answer is `I_say['stairs_1'][2]['stairs_2'][1]['in the door'][2][0]`